# Converting SQL to Django ORM query ("IF" statement inside of a "Window" inside of a "Lead" function)

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to get the date of the next customer that started using a service and append that date to the previous customer.

I was trying to wrap my head around how F() and Q() along with SQL-like functions work in Django, but couldn't wrap my head around how to convert the following SQL statement into valid Django code:

```
            SELECT
            *,
            LEAD(
                IF(actual_start IS NOT NULL, actual_start, planned_start)
                , 1)
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY customer
                    ORDER BY actual_start, planned_start
                ) AS next_starting_time
            FROM builds_build;
```

I tried mashing together some things that I saw:

```
    window = {
        "partition_by": [F('customer')],
        'order_by': [F('actual_start'),F('planned_start')]
    }
    records = Record.objects.annotate(
        next_customer = Window(
            expression = Lead(F('actual_start') if F('actual_start') else F('planned_start'),
             **window)
        )
    )
```

but, looking at the query, the conditional part of the LEAD expression was not taken into account (this is what the Django generated SQL looks like):

```
            SELECT
            *,
            LEAD(actual_start, 1)
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY customer
                    ORDER BY actual_start, planned_start
                ) AS next_starting_time
            FROM builds_build;
```

however, it is completely removing the intended "IF" statement. Any tips and thoughts would be highly appreciated

Comment: set default in Lead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#lead
You could also use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Comment: @iklinac for whatever reason, I didn't even think about COALESCE... Seems to work great - thank you!!!